# Linking Rust code with C SDK on Arm Cortex-A5 architecture after rewriting entry point in Rust

Tags: c, rust, cmake, linker, embedded

I'm developing an Ec200 module using Rust and need to link my Rust code with a C SDK. The Ec200 module has an Arm7a architecture with an Arm Cortex-A5 processor. As part of my development process, I removed the entry point from the C SDK and rewrote it in Rust. Here's the Rust code for the entry point:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn appimg_enter(param: *mut core::ffi::c_void) -> i32 {
    0
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn appimg_exit() {}
```

I then compiled the Rust code successfully using the following command:

```
cargo +nightly-2022-08-10 build -Z build-std=core,alloc  --release --target armv7a-none-eabihf
```

This command generated a **libec200.a** file. Now, I want to link this **libec200.a** file with other libraries using CMake. Here's a summary of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
# Use a global property to collect all application libraries
define_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY app_libraries
    BRIEF_DOCS "app libraries"
    FULL_DOCS "app libraries"
)

# "all_libs" is a target to link all app libraries
set(target all_libs)
set(all_libs_out ${out_lib_dir}/all_libs.a)
get_property(app_libraries GLOBAL PROPERTY app_libraries)

# I add this code to cmake :
list(APPEND app_libraries ${SOURCE_TOP_DIR}/target/armv7a-none-eabihf/release/libec200.a)

list(APPEND app_libraries ${SOURCE_TOP_DIR}/components/ql-kernel/libs/libql_api_dev.a)
list(APPEND app_libraries ${SOURCE_TOP_DIR}/components/ql-kernel/libs/libql_api_adc.a)
if(EXISTS ${SOURCE_TOP_DIR}/components/ql-kernel/libs/liboql_pin_init.a)
    list(APPEND app_libraries ${SOURCE_TOP_DIR}/components/ql-kernel/libs/liboql_pin_init.a)
endif()

list(APPEND app_libraries ${libc_file_name} ${libm_file_name} ${libgcc_file_name} ${QL_LIBS_PATH})
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${all_libs_out}
    COMMAND python3 ${groupgen_py} --base ${BINARY_TOP_DIR} ${all_libs_out} ${app_libraries}
    DEPENDS ${groupgen_py} ${app_libraries}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${BINARY_TOP_DIR}
)
add_custom_target(build_${target} DEPENDS ${all_libs_out})
add_library(${target} STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${all_libs_out})
add_dependencies(${target} build_${target})
```

However, when attempting to link the Rust code with the C SDK, I encounter an error message:

> undefined reference to **appimg_enter**,undefined reference to **appimg_exit**

Could you please help me understand the cause of this error and suggest any possible solutions or additional troubleshooting steps?

I have verified using **nm** that the **libec200.a** file contains the symbols appimg_enter and appimg_exit. Despite this, the linker seems unable to find these symbols during the linking process.